# wordpress rejecting some mp3 - security reason

Tags: wordpress, mp3

I have a wordpress installation bought by others to upload audio-video files. It turns out that some mp3 are accepted while others are rejected with the message:

> wordpress Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

I've never worked before with wordpress and I have no way to log into the server to see what the logs say, but I analized the request made by firefox and in both cases the mimetype is audio/mpeg:

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="async-upload";
>   filename="voice-fabio.mp3" Content-Type: audio/mpeg

the same file, after editing some tags gets rejected. What's the security check that workpress does on uploaded files? I'm really puzzled...

Comment: Difficult to say if you don't have the admin privileges or code to see the generic result.   Try uploading the same mp3 file that worked and see how that goes.  Then check into the smaller details like the codec, duration of the mp3.   wordpress are likely to have restrictions like 3mb uploads on file, no JSON uploads, etc.

Comment: Maybe some bad configs? It is not possible to say anything especially since you pointed out that you bought that theme. Maybe your mp3 is not accepted because it may be malformed. Or it is using some extended tags which are not covered by some scanning modules.

Comment: The answer is that it's a bug. See my answer for the fix and the core.trac link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/39550

> UPDATE: This issue affects more than just Word documents as initially
>   reported. This ticket can be used to track related issues with all
>   non-image files failing to load after 4.7.1 with an error message of
>   Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.

Use this plugin it until WordPress fixes it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-real-mime-check/

Comment: Great! it just worked. Do you also know if there's a real different between files that is triggering this behaviour?

Comment: I don't. I learned about it the day it happened installed the fix.